# Storm Crawler with Java 11

Tags: java-11, stormcrawler

Trying to update the Java version from Java 8 to Java 11 to compile and run the StromCrawler.

**My question-** *Does Storm Crawler is supported on Java 11?*.

As we I update the java version in my POM and build the project I was successfully build the project but when I tried to run the project I am getting the Following error while running the InjectorTopology-

````
560  [main] INFO  c.a.h.c.InjectorTopology - ####### The Injector Topology Started #######
563  [main] INFO  c.a.h.c.u.PropertyFileReader - Enter Load Properties File
564  [main] INFO  c.a.h.c.u.PropertyFileReader - Exit Load Properties File
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.base/java.lang.J9VMInternals.ensureError(J9VMInternals.java:186)
        at java.base/java.lang.J9VMInternals.recordInitializationFailure(J9VMInternals.java:175)
        at clojure.lang.Namespace.<init>(Namespace.java:34)
        at clojure.lang.Namespace.findOrCreate(Namespace.java:176)
        at clojure.lang.Var.internPrivate(Var.java:151)
        at org.apache.storm.LocalCluster.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.ConfigurableTopology.submit(ConfigurableTopology.java:75)
        at com.vinn.hel.crawler.InjectorTopology.run(InjectorTopology.java:57)
        at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.ConfigurableTopology.start(ConfigurableTopology.java:50)
        at com.vinn.hel.crawler.InjectorTopology.main(InjectorTopology.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must hint overloaded method: toArray, compiling:(clojure/gvec.clj:131:1)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6730)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6524)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6485)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:5861)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$LetExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:6179)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6723)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6524)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6485)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:5861)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$FnMethod.parse(Compiler.java:5296)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$FnExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3925)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6721)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6524)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6779)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7227)
        at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:371)
        at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:362)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:446)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:412)
        at clojure.core$load$fn__1621.invoke(core.clj:5866)
        at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5865)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at clojure.core$eval2892.invoke(core.clj:6497)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6782)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7227)
        at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:371)
        at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:362)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:446)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:412)
        at clojure.lang.RT.doInit(RT.java:454)
        at clojure.lang.RT.<clinit>(RT.java:330)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must hint overloaded method: toArray
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$NewInstanceMethod.parse(Compiler.java:8050)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$NewInstanceExpr.build(Compiler.java:7642)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$NewInstanceExpr$DeftypeParser.parse(Compiler.java:7523)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6723)
        ... 38 more```
````

Comment: Judging purely from the stacktrace (and having no other experience with either stormcrawler and Clojure) it sounds like it's actually Clojure that has a problem with Java 11 and you might have to upgrade Clojure itself (or stormcrawler to a newer version that bundles a newer clojure).

Answer (score 0):

To add to Joachim's comment, it looks like Clojure 1.8 is needed in order to run Java 11. Storm 1.2.3 comes with Clojure 1.7.

You could override the dependency in the POM of your StormCrawler project but this will work only in local mode. In deployed mode, you'd also need to change the dependency where Storm is installed.

It might be easier to use StormCrawler 2.x and the latest Apache Storm, which does not depend on Clojure at all or simply run it with Java 8.

Comment: Thanks Julien, we may go for the StromCrawler 2.x. currently we are going to use Java 8.